# Question about the closure under addition property of a field.

Tags: field-theory

I was reading over notes that explain the following:

> When discussing fields, we should distinguish that which can be claimed as
> a basic field property ((A),(M), and (D)) from properties that can (and must) be
> proved from the basic field properties. For example, given that $(\mathbb{F},+,\bullet)$ is a field,
> we can claim that $(\forall x)(\forall y)(x,y \in \mathbb{F} \rightarrow x + y \in \mathbb{F})$ as an alternative description of property (A1) while we can not claim that additive inverses are unique

If (A1) is originally defined as follows,

(A1) $+: \mathbb{F}$ x $\mathbb{F} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$

Could we still replace (A1) with (A1)* $(\forall x)(\forall y)(x,y \in \mathbb{F} \rightarrow x + y \in \mathbb{F})$ if we did not list out all the field axioms that $(\mathbb{F},+,e)$ satisfies (that is, if we did not know that $(\mathbb{F},+,e)$ is a field)?

Comment: It might be helpful if you provided a link to the notes you're referring to. However, I'm a little confused by what your concern is about not listing the field axioms (and by what you mean by not knowing that $(\Bbb{F},+,e)$ is a field). (A1) simply says that $+$ is a binary operation on $\Bbb{F}$; i.e., a function $+ : \Bbb{F}\times\Bbb{F}\to\Bbb{F}.$ This is the same as saying that given any two elements $x,y\in\Bbb{F}$, there exists a unique element $x+y\in\Bbb{F}$ determined by $x$ and $y.$ This has nothing to do with $\Bbb{F}$ being a field; binary operations make sense on any set.

Comment: What is the $e$ in your field description? A field is a set $\Bbb{F}$ with two binary operations $+,\cdot : \Bbb{F}\times\Bbb{F}\to\Bbb{F}$ satisfying a number of properties. Did you mean $\cdot$ instead of $e$?

Comment: $e$ is the additive identity. These are the notes that I'm referring to: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~emsilvia/math127/chapter1.pdf

Comment: @Stahl: I wasn't sure if the $(\forall x)(\forall y)(x,y \in \mathbb{F} \rightarrow x + y \in \mathbb{F})$ axiom makes sense until we find out that a field has at least two distinct elements.

Comment: @Stahl: But I guess thinking about it some more, $x,y \in \mathbb{F}$ could be the same element. Although, I think that maybe $(\forall x)(\forall y)(x,y \in \mathbb{F} \rightarrow x + y \in \mathbb{F})$ sounds better once we know that there's more than one element in a field?

Comment: Minor note: $(\Bbb{F},+,e)$ is not the data of a field -- only the data of a group (assuming that $+$ is associative and that $\Bbb{F}$ has additive inverses). However, you are right that the statement $(\forall x)(\forall x)(x,y\in\Bbb{F}\implies x+y\in\Bbb{F})$ makes sense even if $\Bbb{F}$ doesn't have more than one element (you certainly do still want this to work if $x = y$). In fact, this statement still makes sense if $\Bbb{F} = \emptyset$.

Comment: However, I have a small quibble with the alternate version of (A1) -- the data of a field is defined to be $\Bbb{F}$ together with the binary operations $+,\cdot$. The fact that $+$ is a binary operation is precisely the statement that $+$ is a function $+:\Bbb{F}\times\Bbb{F}\to\Bbb{F},$ so (A1) says exactly that $+$ is a binary operation on $\Bbb{F}$. However, the second version, that $x,y\in\Bbb{F}\implies x+y\in\Bbb{F}$ doesn't even make sense if you haven't defined $+$ yet! You need to say that $+$ is a function $\Bbb{F}\times\Bbb{F}\to\Bbb{F}$, but this makes the alternate (A1) trivial.